# ion-refresher is not refreshing the page content

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to refresh the page by calling the service again in the function but I'm failing to do... here is the code:

```
export class JobsPage {
   jobs: Jobs[]

     constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private jobsData: JobsData) {

      jobsData.load().then(res => {
         this.jobs = res; 
        })
      }

     doRefresh(refresh){

        setTimeout(() => {
         this.jobsData.load().then(res => {
         this.jobs = res;
         }); 
        refresh.complete();
        }, 1000);
     }
```

As you see I am running the service this.jobsData.load() again in the refresher function, however the new data is not updated... unless I completely refresh the web page in order to load the new data

in the html I have placed the refresher right under `<ion-content>`

```
 <ion-content>
   <ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
     <ion-refresher-content 
       pullingIcon="arrow-dropdown"
       pullingText="Pull to refresh"
       refreshingSpinner="circles"
       refreshingText="Refreshing...">
     </ion-refresher-content>
   </ion-refresher>

  <ion-card *ngFor="let job of jobs">
   //// the page content
   </ion-card>
  </ion-content>
```

I am including the service.ts code as well:

```
  load() {
    if (this.data) {
      return Promise.resolve(this.data);
    }
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get(this.jobsApiUrl)
       .map(res => res.json())
       .subscribe(data => {
         this.data = data.data;
         resolve(this.data);
       });
     });
    }
```

.subscribe is for accessing data api `{ data: {.....}, category: {.....} }`
I couldn't find a way to this with `Observable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try completing the refresh action after async operation is complete.
Put the complete function call inside then.

```
  doRefresh(refresh){

        setTimeout(() => {
         this.jobsData.load().then(res => {
         this.jobs = res;
        refresh.complete();//here
         }); 
        }, 1000);
     }
```

Edit Also,
set the ion-card list of jobs within the ion-refresher-content.

```
    <ion-content>
       <ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
         <ion-refresher-content 
           pullingIcon="arrow-dropdown"
           pullingText="Pull to refresh"
           refreshingSpinner="circles"
           refreshingText="Refreshing...">
//here
      <ion-card *ngFor="let job of jobs">
       //// the page content
       </ion-card>
         </ion-refresher-content>
       </ion-refresher>


      </ion-content>
```

Your service method is returning same data because you have saved it in service class.Either load each time..

```
 load() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get(this.jobsApiUrl)
       .map(res => res.json())
       .subscribe(data => {
         this.data = data.data;
         resolve(this.data);
       });
     });
    }
```

or have a method to remove data object in your service and call it in your refresh method before load.

Comment: any reason you are using timeout?

Comment: it didnt work out... im using timeout as per of the documetation.. it set the duration for `<ion-refresher-content>`

Comment: If anything within ion-refresher-content.... I get a blank page and only refresher is working when pulling down

Comment: @tusharbalar I have added service.ts as well , can you please see... I think the problem persists there

Answer (score -1):

I think execution of http service takes some time,

so your refresh.complete() execute before getting resposne from server.

***Try to do this:***

```
export class JobsPage implements onInit {

  jobs: Jobs[]

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private jobsData: JobsData) {
    this.loadData();
  }

  loadData() {
    jobsData.load().then(res => {
     this.jobs = res; 
    });
  }

  doRefresh(refresh){
     jobsData.load().then(res => {
       // To check response data format
       console.log("data from server", res);
       this.jobs = res;
       refresh.complete();
     });
  }

}
```

**Yout html is look likes:**

```
<ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
  <ion-refresher-content></ion-refresher-content>
</ion-refresher>
```

And also i am doing same kind of thing in my project and it's working for me,
please check once it will help you

```
complaintRefresh(refresher) {
    // Set currnt page
    this.currentPage = 1;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.c.getComplaints(this.currentPage).subscribe((complaints) => {
        // Handle htp response status
        if (complaints.status === 204) {
          this.EmptyComplaints = true;
        } else {
          this.EmptyComplaints = false;
          this.complaints = complaints.json();
        }
      }, (err) => {
        this.nl.showToast("Internal Server Error.. please try again");
      });
      refresher.complete();
    }, 1000);
  }
```

Comment: Sometimes it better to use ngOnInit() instead of constructor() to execute this kind of process

Comment: @SurajRao @ tusharbalar I considered what you said...but OnInit will only fire once. instead in ionic 2 a better life hook is `ionViewWillEnter()` so I tried that as well but no use...the thing is the data I receive back when I call the service again inside `doRefresh()` function, it's not being updated/reloaded , when I log it, its still the same data... Its only fired once the first time...!!

Comment: I solve the problem by just removing `if (this.data) { return Promise.resolve(this.data); }`  but I am interested to know if there is a way to return `data` part of the API using `Observables`